# How can I get the key from the event object when I handle the method In React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, onclick, key

The e.key is undefined when I click the DOM element;
How can I fecth the key of the DOM?

### Source code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.__handle = this.__handle.bind(this);
}

__handle(e){
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.key);
}

render() {

    let that = this;
    let data = [1,2,3,4];
    let com = data.map(function(data,index){
        return <div key={index} onClick={that.__handle}>data</div>
    })

    return <div>
        {com}
    </div>;
}
```

The version of React is ^15.6.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `e.keyCode` ?

Comment: Yes. But it is undefined

Comment: keyCode doesn't exist for onClick. Did you meant `onkeypress` or `onkeydown` ?

Comment: See this demo https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KnSgoK5Hm8fGOA3SR-9 .

Answer (score 0):

I thought you had this kind of doubt.

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.handleClick = this.handleClick(this);
    }

    handleClick(data){
       console.log(data);
    }

    render(){
       let data = [1,2,3,4];
       return data.map(val=>{
           return <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, val)}>{val}</div>
       })
    }
}
```

I hope this is useful for you!